# Cannot update the timestamp with timezone in postgres using golang

Tags: postgresql, go, beego

I am using golang and postgreSQL version 9.5.5 in my application. I am using "github.com/lib/pq" as my database driver to connect to the database. One of my fields have the type timestamp with timezone. I would like to update to the current time. So I used the following code:

> Note:I m using beego as my framework and use orm to compute my
>   queries.

```
_, err := o.Raw("UPDATE leave SET resultdate=? WHERE leaveid=?",  time.Now(), leaveResult.LeaveId).Exec()
```

When I execute this I'm getting the following error:

```
"pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: \"09:24:29\""
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: High probability that DB expects a different date/time format. For example RFC3339.
Try saving instead of time.Now() with 
time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)

Comment: Thanks mpmlj .Its working.Saved my day.....

Comment: awesome!! Moving to an actual answer for others to use as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

High probability that DB expects a different date/time format. For example RFC3339. Try saving instead of time.Now() with time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)